# how to perform math operation on a variable into flask template

Tags: python, html, css, templates, flask

I just need to perform this

```
{% i += 1 %}
```

but I end with this error

```
jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError:
       expected token 'end of statement block', got '+'
```

---

#### problem is to perform a math operation within a loop and every time the variable should change.. not printing it

---

#### edit

I reached this point `{% set i = sum([i, 1]) %}`

but within for loop it prints 111111111 not 123456789 '_'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jinja math operations does not allow the operator `+=`. You can see the available operators [here](https://jinja.palletsprojects.com/en/2.11.x/templates/#math)

You can do something like

```
{% set count =  i + 1 %}
```

Given `i` is already a defined variable.

Comment: I need to work with the same variable I defined before for loob

Comment: Can you update your full code to the question? Its hard to understand the context of the problem with only a line of code.

Answer (score 1):

try to do the following code, just do the math operation before. it worked for me.

```
i+=1
return render_template("file.html",i=i)
```

And write in your html file the following line:

```
<p>{{i}}</p>
```

Comment: problem is to perform a math operation within a loop and every time the variable should change.. not printing it